# AVAudioPlayer not working anymore

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

This program was working before and I do not believe I changed anything. Here is the code. I get the thrown error : file not found: bgMusic

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }
        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }


    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        playBackgroundMusic("bgMusic")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the file path instead. This works for me everytime.

```
//Change 'ofType' to whatever the file type is. (.m4a, .mp3, etc.)
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: ".mp3")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
```

Then load the url into the AVAudioPlayer.

If that doesn't work, then make sure the filename is correct and that it is added into your project. Best of luck!

Comment: " Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" This is on the second line

Comment: Unwrap the optional by adding '!' after path. It should be safe to assume your file is there if you added it. If it crashes, then your file is probably not in the project correctly or the filename is wrong.